# Serializing form data returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I'm trying populating a dynamic list from JSON API , I need to serialize the form data then use it to fire AJAX request , but it returns undefined.

```js
var s_name = '';

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url1 = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx91EB9aIOXRYNmP108ZcPuEGgUqZWZli0KWdj5A3Ts0Qc6hrc/exec";

  $.getJSON(url1, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      var $option = $('<option value="' + value.ID + '">' + value.Client + '</option>');
      $option.text();
      // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
      $('#clist').append($option);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").text($("form").serialize());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="clist">Select Client Name</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="clist" name="clist" style="width:100%">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  </select>
</form>

<button>Test</button>
<div></div>
```

Comment: Exactly what part of this code is returning `undefined`?

Comment: I'm using a button as test to see if the data is serialized or not ! if you clicked it , it should return the serialized data . but in this code it returns >>> clist=undefined<<<

Comment: The problem is because if you `console.log(value)` within the `each()` block you'll see the object that's returned only has a `Client` property. The `ID` property does not exist, hence you are appending `undefined` in to the HTML. You need to determine why the `ID` property is not being returned as you expect.,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you did works, the problem is that your return only brings the client's name not his id

```js
var s_name = '';

$(document).ready(function() {
  var url1 = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbx91EB9aIOXRYNmP108ZcPuEGgUqZWZli0KWdj5A3Ts0Qc6hrc/exec";

  $.getJSON(url1, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(index, value) {
      var $option = $('<option value="' + value.Client + '">' + value.Client + '</option>');
      $option.text();
      // APPEND OR INSERT DATA TO SELECT ELEMENT.
      $('#clist').append($option);
    });
  });
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    $("div").text($("form").serialize());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <label for="clist">Select Client Name</label>
  <select class="form-control" id="clist" name="clist" style="width:100%">
    <option value="">-- Select --</option>
  </select>
</form>

<button>Test</button>
<div></div>
```